# Where does etherpad store final atext/attribs when connected to MySql?

Tags: etherpad

I have connected etherpad to database mysql by making changes in settings.json file. On changing anything in etherpad, revisions changesets are being stored in mysql.But when i change something in changeset manually in database and restart/reload the etherpad doc again the changes made my me are not displayed in etherpad. So i assume it might possible that etherpad might be storing the final atext somewhere so that it doesn't have to apply each changeset revision one by one. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer.It stores the complete atext and value too in database against key pad:padID.